# How to create a new (third) button besides i like it and tags & notes?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, social

I'm trying to create a third button that sits beside the "i like it" and "tags & notes" buttons. So far I have managed to add my button on the ListItem and Documents ribbon tabs:

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.TagsAndNotes.Controls._children">
```

and

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.TagsAndNotes.Controls._children">
```

But I can't find the right location to add it to the controls on the "Browse" tab. How can I add my button there?

Comment: How about adding your button the the master page?

Comment: I'd like to do this as close to best practices as possible, plus editing the master page is in this case no option :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of SharePoint 2010, you can edit your master page with Designer. Find the following node:

```
<td class="s4-socialdata-notif">
 <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink3" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/>                                      
</td>
```

Then add another **td** before or after this one.

For instance, this is what I did withing 30 seconds using this technique:

[image: New button]

**Update:**

As Hinek pointed out, the best way to do it, is by adding a custom control to the page using a delegate control for the ControlID: **GlobalSiteLink3**. So, [check this link as an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/569897/UsingplusDelegateplusControlplusinplusSharepoint)

Comment: Thanks, I will not edit the master page, but you showed me, the area is a DelegateControl, so I will try to add a new control to it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Delegate control is the best way to go here. I've just shown the easiest way.